# Show the polynomial is irreducible in $\textbf Z_2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

**Show that $p(\gamma) = \gamma^{4} + \gamma + 1$ is irreducible over $\textbf Z_2$.**
Okay, I would just like to see if i'm on the right track for this problem.

$$\gamma^{4}+\gamma+1=(\gamma +b)(c\gamma^{3}+d\gamma^{2}+e\gamma+\gamma)$$
So then $a = c = 1$.

So $$\gamma^{4}+\gamma+1=(\gamma +b)(\gamma^{3}+d\gamma^{2}+e\gamma+\gamma)$$

Let $b = 0$
$\gamma^{4} + \gamma+1=(\gamma)(\gamma^{3}+d\gamma^{2}+e\gamma+\gamma)$

Let $\gamma = 0$
Then we see $1 = 0$ which is a contradiction.

Let $b = 1$
$\gamma^{4}+\gamma+1=(\gamma+1)(\gamma^{3}+d\gamma^{2}+e\gamma+\gamma)$

Take $\gamma = 1$
And again
$1=0$

***So our polynomial is irreducible over $\textbf Z_2$***

Is there another way I should be computing this?
Maybe with Long division of polynomials? 
I'm quite lost..

Comment: Clearly $p$ has no roots in $\Bbb Z_2$, so all that's left to show is that $p$ can't factor as a product of two quadratics in $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: Note: if $p(\gamma)=(\gamma +b)(c\gamma^{3}+d\gamma^{2}+e\gamma+f)$, then $p(b)=0$, which is easily ruled out.

Comment: What is $a$ at the third line? And why $e\gamma+\gamma$?

Comment: How do I just show that it can't factor as a product of two quadratics?

Comment: @Aldrec You only have to check one polynomial. If your polynomial is not divisible by $\color \green {x^2+x+1}$, you have shown that it cannot be a product of two quadratics.

Comment: So, in total, you only have to check the three polynomials $x$ , $x+1$ and $x^2+x+1$. If a polynomial of degree $4$ is not divisble by any of those,it is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$

Comment: To show that your polynomial is not divisible by $x^2+x+1$, consider $(x^2+x+1)^2\equiv x^4+x^2+1\mod 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's 'bout this:

Set

$p(x) = x^4 + x + 1 \in \Bbb Z_2[x]; \tag 0$

then

$p(\gamma) = \gamma^4 + \gamma+ 1 \ne 0 \tag 1$

for any $\gamma \in \Bbb Z_2$; therefore $p(x)$ has no factor of degree one in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$; thus if $p(x)$ is *not* irreducible, it be the product of two quadratics

$a(x) = a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0 \in \Bbb Z_2[x], \tag 2$

and

$b(x) = b_2 x^2 + b_2 x + b_0 \in \Bbb Z_2[x]; \tag 3$

that is,

$p(x) = a(x)b(x); \tag 4$

it follows from (0), (2)-(4) that

$a_2 b_2 = 1 \tag 5$

and

$a_0 b_0 = 1; \tag 6$

now note that ***the only solutions to (5)-(6) in $\Bbb Z_2$*** are

$a_2 = b_2 = a_0 = b_0 = 1; \tag 7$

thus

$a(x) = x^2 + a_1 x + 1, \tag 8$

$b(x) = x^2 + b_1 x + 1; \tag 9$

we have

$x^4 + x + 1 = p(x) = a(x)b(x) = (x^2 + a_1 x + 1)(x^2 + b_1 x + 1)$
$= x^4 + (a_1 + b_1)x^3 + 2x^2 + a_1 b_1 x^2 + (a_1 + b_1)x + 1$
$= x^4 + (a_1 + b_1)x^3 + a_1 b_1 x^2 + (a_1 + b_1)x + 1; \tag{10}$

comparing coefficients, it follows that

$a_1 + b_1 = 0, \tag{11}$

$a_1 b_1 = 0, \tag{12}$

and

$a_1 + b_1 = 1; \tag{13}$

clearly (11)-(13) have no solution in $\Bbb Z_2$; indeed (11) and (13) directly contradict each other, implying as they do $1 = 0$.  Therefore no such polynomials $a(x)$, $b(x)$ exist in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$, and so $p(x)$ must be irreducible.

***Note Added in Edit Sunday 24 September 2017 9:08 AM PST:***  This note addresses our OP Aldrec's comment to this answer, which in essence asks if a technique similar to that used above can be used to determine the reducibility/irreducibility over $\Bbb Z_2$ of the quintic polynomial

$q(x) = x^5 -x^4 + x^2 - x + 1; \tag{14}$

the answer is yes it can, as follows:

We first note that, over $\Bbb Z_2$, $q(x)$ may be written

$q(x) = x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1, \tag{15}$

since $-1 = 1$ in $\Bbb Z_2$.  The form (15) of $q(x)$ will make the arithmetic and bookkeeping a little easier.  Next we see that

$q(0) = q(1) = 1, \tag{16}$

which shows that $q(x)$ has no root in $\Bbb Z_2$, hence no linear factor in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$.  So if $q(x)$ is reducible, it must have on quadratic and one cubic factor.  To investigate this prospect, we set

$a(x) = a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0 \tag{17}$

and

$b(x) = b_3x^3 + b_2 x^2 + b_1 x + b_0, \tag{18}$

and set

$q(x) = a(x)b(x) = (a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0)(b_3x^3 + b_2 x^2 + b_1 x + b_0); \tag{19}$

before proceeding any further we see by comparing (19) and (15) that we must have

$a_2b_3 = a_0b_0 = 1, \tag{20}$

which implies

$a_2 = b_3 = a_0 = b_0 = 1; \tag{21}$

substituting these values into (19) yields

$q(x) = (x^2 + a_1x + 1)(x^3 + b_2x^2 + b_1x + 1); \tag{22}$

we next perform the multiplication indicated on the right of (22) and see that

$x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1 = q(x) = a(x)b(x) = (x^2 + a_1x + 1)(x^3 + b_2x^2 + b_1x + 1)$
$= x^5 + (a_1 + b_2)x^4 + (b_1 + a_1 b_2 + 1)x^3 + (a_1b_1 + b_2 + 1)x^2 + (a_1 + b_1)x + 1,  \tag{23}$

and so we conclude that

$a_1 + b_2 = a_1b_1 + b_2 + 1 = a_1 + b_1 = 1 \tag{24}$

and

$b_1 + a_1 b_2 + 1 = 0. \tag{25}$

It is easy to see that (24), (25) have no solution in $\Bbb Z_2$; if $a_1 = 0$, (24) yields

$b_2 = b_2 + 1, \tag{26}$

clearly impossible; whereas if $a_1 = 1$, (24) forces

$b_1 = b_2 = 0, \tag{27}$

which contradicts (25).  We conclude there are no polynomials $a(x), b(x) \in \Bbb Z_2[x]$ satisfying (19); thus $q(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_2$.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: Ah I see thank you, Could I use this method to show that P(x)=x^5-x^4+x^2+1 is irreducible as well?  What product would I write it as in this case? It'd have to be a product of more then 2 polynomials no?

Comment: $x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + 1$ has a zero at $x = 1$; therefore $(x - 1) \mid (x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + 1)$ and so  $x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + 1$ is reducible in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$.

Comment: P(x) = x^5 - x^4 + x^2 - x + 1 is the polynomial I meant sorry

Comment: @Aldrec:  I get $1^5 + 1^4 + 1^2 + 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$; four $1$s, hence, 0 in $\Bbb Z_2$.  Where did you get the extra "$1$"?  or did I goof?

Comment: @Aldred:  well, $x^5 - x^4 + x^2 - x + 1$ is a different story!

Comment: could I show that its irreducible  
 
$P(x) = x^5 - x^4 + x^2 - x + 1$ I'm unsure what product of polynomials i'd set it equal to, to get a similar argument for the other polynomial

Comment: I'd try $a(x)$ as I presented it, and $b(x) = b_3 x^3 + b_2 x^2 + b_1 x + 1$; then you should get $a_2 b_3 = 1$ and $a_0 b_0 = 1$, so $a_2 = b_3 = a_0 = b_0$; then plug these values into $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ and see what happens.

Comment: I should add that $a_2 = b_3 = a_0 = b_0 = 1$.

Comment: @Aldrec:  I amended my answer to deal with $x^5 - x^4 + x^2 - x + 1$ as well,

Answer (score 3):

Robert Lewis did a great job, but I think that his exposition could perhaps be shortened.  Consider
$$
p(x)=x^4+x+1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]
$$
Since $p(0)=1$ and $p(1) = 1$, the original $p(x)$ has not root and thus cannot be factored into the product of a cubic and a first degree polynomial.

If it could be factored, then both quadratics would have to be of the form:
$$
x^2+ax+1
$$
because the first and last coefficients of both quadratics multiply up to unity in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  If either of the two quadratics had $a=0$, then $p(1)=0$, contradicting the fact that $p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ has no roots.  And if both quadratics had $a=1$, then $p(x)$ would have to have non-zero coefficients for the $x^3$ and $x^2$ terms, again a contradiction.

Comment: My expositions can always be shortened.  Cheers! :)

Comment: $(x^2 + x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1) = x^4 + x^3 + x^3 + x^2 + x^2 + x^2 + x + x + 1 = x^4 + x^2 + 1$ in $\Bbb Z_2$.  Both quadratic factors have $a = 1$, but the product has zero as the coefficient of $x^3$.

Answer (score 2):

$x^4+x+1$ clearly has no root in $\mathbb{F}_2$. Since the only quadratic irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is $x^2+x+1$ and $x^2+x+1$ is not a divisor of $x^4+x+1$, $x^4+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$.